# mapnik geojson vector tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, mapbox, mapnik

Could you point me in the right direction on how to create vector tiles from geojson or topojson?
mapnik-vector-tile seems to be the right library but I cannot find a good example.
There seems to be examples of geojson files (14_2620_6331-XXX) but how did the pbf files get created?
Thanks.
Pat.

Answer (score 0):

[Tippecanoe](https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe) is the best way to create vector tiles from vector file formats (like `.geojson`).

Their [usage on the readme](https://github.com/felt/tippecanoe#usage) has good tutorials, e.g.:

```
tippecanoe -o file.mbtiles [options] mydata.geojson
```

Answer (score -1):

The vector tile code [has a repository with examples, including output in protobuf](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile/tree/master/examples).